# Writing a custom loss function without y_true in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I'm implementing a triplet loss function in Keras. In general, loss functions take predicted values with ground truth as arguments. But triplet loss doesn't use labels, just the output. I tried to write the function with just one parameter:

```
def triplet_loss(y_pred):
    margin = 1
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred[0]) - K.square(y_pred[1]) + margin)
```

It failed saying `triplet_loss()` takes 1 argument but two arguments were given (in `score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)`. When I write the function with two arguments `y_true, y_pred`, the program runs without error. Why is that? Should I just implement this function with these two arguments although `y_true` won't be used? Is this correct or is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well.... simply don't use the ground truth:

```
def triplet_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    #all your code as it is.
```

It's not very usual to have networks trained without ground truth. When we expect it to learn something, there is very very often a ground truth. If you don't, simply ignore it.

Also, if `y_true` is ignored, what are you passing to the fit method? Just a dummy array?

Comment: I did't solved it yet, I'm just trying to deal with it now.

Comment: I wonder if this is still the best solution with tf 2.3 out now?

Comment: @sachinruk, It's possible to use `model.add_loss(some_calculated_tensor)` and probably compile with `loss=None`.

Answer (score 1):

implement it via K.function method.

```
output_tensor = your_model(input_tensor)
total_loss = K.mean( K.abs (input_tensor - output_tensor) )

nn_train = K.function ([input_tensor],[total_loss], 
                Adam(lr=5e-5, beta_1=0.5, beta_2=0.999).get_updates(total_loss, your_model.trainable_weights)

loss, = nn_train ([input])
```